# Using libraries in Eclipse without altering classpath

Tags: java, eclipse

**Edit:**

How can I included packages in the `.classpath` that are downloaded at compile-time by `gradlew` and use them in Eclipse **before** compile-time such that my `.classpath` doesnt include local file paths from my personal computer?

I would like to use the `org.apache.commons.cli` package, but do so without altering the `.classpath` file. I'm using the `gradlew` to build my project, and in the `build.gradle` file is:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'commons-cli:commons-cli:20040117.000000'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.11" 
}
```

So at compile-time, the necessary libraries are managed. However, without them added to Eclipse, using them seems to be impossible as they cannot be resolved.

**Question:**

If using `build.gradle` to manage project dependencies, is there a way to use them in Eclipse without going to the project's build path and adding external jar's? If not, what is the general practice for situations like this, where a library is needed to be use, but I dont want my local file path stored in the `.classpath`, where a user may not have the same jar in the same file path?

Comment: @JimGarrison Oh no they will be in the classpath, but `gradlew` manages them on the CI runner, I dont care how, but it does. However, when I am writing new code in Eclipse, I have to alter the projects build path to say point to `C:\Users\datta\java-jars\commons-cli-1.4.jar`. Well thats fine and dandy for on my computer, but I dont want a `.classpath` stored on the repository with file paths pointing to jar's a user who downloads the program may (and likely wont) or may not have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install and use [Eclipse BuildShip](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship) to properly work with gradle projects.

Comment: Turns out just needed to do `Project > Gradle > Refresh...`